# add different children to an element in a xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to add some children to an element on my xml file like this :

```
<test>
  <parameter type="double" name="PHONE_NUMBER" />
  <parameter type="string" name="NAME" />
  <parameter type="string" name="E-MAIL" />
  ...
</test>
```

I've tried somthing like this :

```
$input = simplexml_load_file('new.xml');
$input->test="";
$input->test->addChild("parameter");
$input->test->parameter->addAttribute("type", "double");
$input->test->parameter->addAttribute("name", "PHONE_NUMBER");

$input->test->addChild("parameter");
$input->test->parameter->addAttribute("type", "string");
$input->test->parameter->addAttribute("name", "NAME");
...
```

But I get this error message :

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute() [simplexmlelement.addattribute]:
>   Attribute already exists

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Start Add as you wish !! And once you stuck up, shows us how you Add

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "gimme ze code question"

Comment: @Php_cpp Yes, possible. $node->addChild('child');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st, you cant access the xml root element so wrap your xml for examle `'<xml>'.$yourXML.'</xml>`

2nd simpleXML doesn't understand what a parametr tag you access. Save point to added child and modify it

```
$str = '<xml><test>
  <parameter type="double" name="PHONE_NUMBER" />
  <parameter type="string" name="NAME" />
  <parameter type="string" name="E-MAIL" />
</test></xml>';

$input = simplexml_load_string($str);
$input->test="";

$child = $input->test->addChild("parameter");
$child->addAttribute("type", "double");
$child->addAttribute("name", "PHONE_NUMBER");

$child = $input->test->addChild("parameter");
$child->addAttribute("type", "string");
$child->addAttribute("name", "NAME");

echo $input->saveXML();
```